# Why does pydantic not encode my bool in json?

Tags: python, pydantic

I want to have Pydantic write booleans as either "y" or "n". The [Pydantic documentation on encoders](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#json_encoders) suggests that I can configure a way to encode values based on their data type, in my case `bool`.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyStuff(BaseModel):
    do_it: bool = False

    class Config:
        json_encoders = {
            bool: lambda b: "y" if b else "n",
        }

ms = MyStuff()
print(ms.json(exclude_defaults=False))
```

When I run this, I get

> {"do_it": false}

when I expected

> {"do_it": "n"}

Other tries:

- It does not matter whether I specify a default or not.
- I cannot get it to work for other basic data types like `int` either, but it does work for `pathlib.Path`.
- It does not work either if I replace the `lambda` with a function like this:

```
def convert_my_bool(b: bool) -> str:
    if b:
        return "y"
    return "n"

class MyStuff(BaseModel):
    do_it: bool

    class Config:
        json_encoders = {
            bool: convert_my_bool,
        }
```

What am I missing here? How do I need to write my `Config` to write booleans in my model as "y" or "n"?

Comment: Did you try not giving `do_it` a default value?

Comment: @barny Yes, unfortunately that doesn't make a difference. I've added more failed attempts to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import orjson
from pydantic import BaseModel


def orjson_dumps(v, *, default=None):
    for key, value in v.items():
        if isinstance(value, bool):
            v[key] = "y" if value else "n"

    return orjson.dumps(
        v,
        default=default,
    ).decode()


class MyStuff(BaseModel):
    do_it: bool = False

    class Config:
        # Change default json encoders/decoders to orjson ones
        json_loads = orjson.loads
        json_dumps = orjson_dumps


ms = MyStuff()
print(ms.json(exclude_defaults=False))
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to avoid that... I could also get `MyStuff` as a dict, then modify the items I want to modify and JSON-encode it myself. Your solution is a bit better because mine would be tied to the key names and yours is generic by data type. I'm still wondering if there is an easier way though.

Comment: Don't just post a code dump. Explain what the problem is and how this solves it.

Comment: Agree with @Barmar. Without description it is still unclear why `json_encoders` wouldn't work (despite being encouraged in documentation).